# How to insert Salesforce Activity History contents into custom field of a Contact?

Tags: contact, activities

I am using Gmail, Salesforce integration app, using which I can save an interested mail into Salesforce Activity History of a Contact. Now, as soon as I receive the activity history, I want to save this into a custom field, named EmailBody__c.

I have tried with the below trigger but have no luck

```
trigger EmailBodyTrigger on Contact(before update) {
    Contact[] contacts = Trigger.new;
    for(Contact c : contacts) {
        try {
            ActivityHistory ah = c.ActivityHistories;
            if(ah != null) {
                contact.EmailBody__c = 'Hello Ram, How are you';
            }
        } catch(System.QueryException e) {
          // no trigger call   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating/creating an activity history doesn't affect on the contact DML operations so you need to use a trigger on Task instead of trigger on Contact then add required restrictions into the trigger in order to do your actions on the `EmailBody__c` field.

Below is just a simple:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Task (before update) {

    final Task tsk = Trigger.new[0];
    final ID whoId = tsk.WhoId;

    if(String.isNotEmpty(whoId)){
        try {
            final Schema.sObjectType entityType = whoId.getSObjectType();
            if(entityType == Contact.sObjectType){
                final Contact cnt = [Select Id, EmailBody__c from Contact where id=:whoId];
                cnt.EmailBody__c = 'Hello Ram, How are you';
                update cnt;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //Ignore...
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks.  As I am pretty new to SF apex, can you please, if possible, share the exact code, instead of this sample.

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look